# Question about using Ito's formula for Poisson Processes

Tags: real-analysis, probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, poisson-process

Let $M_t$ be the compensated process associate the Poisson Process $N_t$ with intensity $\lambda_t.$ Then consider a smooth function $F(t,X_t)$ where $dX_t = \alpha_t dt + \beta_t dN_t.$

By Ito's formula, we have,
$$F(t,X_t) = F(0,X_0) + \int_0^t \left[\partial_s F(s,X_s) + \partial_x F(s,X_s) \alpha_s\right] ds + \sum_{s\leq t} F(s,X_s) -F(s,X_{s-})$$
which can be re-written as
$$F(t,X_t) = F(0,X_0) + \int_0^t \left[\partial_s F(s,X_s) + \partial_x F(s,X_s) \alpha_s\right] ds + \int_0^t \left[F(s,X_{s-}+\beta_s) -F(s,X_{s-})\right]dN_s.$$

Since $dM_s=dN_s - \lambda_s ds$ I can further re-write the above expression as follows,
$$F(t,X_t) = F(0,X_0) + \int_0^t \left[\partial_s F(s,X_s) + \partial_x F(s,X_s) \alpha_s+\left(F(s,X_{s-}+\beta_s) -F(s,X_{s-})\right)\lambda_s\right] ds + \int_0^t \left[F(s,X_{s-}+\beta_s) -F(s,X_{s-})\right]dM_s.$$

Is this final expression correct and also can I get rid of $X_{s-}$ in the $ds$ integral and write
$$F(t,X_t) = F(0,X_0) + \int_0^t \left[\partial_s F(s,X_s) + \partial_x F(s,X_s) \alpha_s+\left(F(s,X_{s}+\beta_s) -F(s,X_{s})\right)\lambda_s\right] ds + \int_0^t \left[F(s,X_{s-}+\beta_s) -F(s,X_{s-})\right]dM_s?$$

I have read in these [lecture notes, Proposition 1.3.2](https://www.maths.univ-evry.fr/pages_perso/jeanblanc/conferences/Cimpa-sauts.pdf) for instance that this can be done since the set of jump times forms a countable set. But is there a rigorous justification for this fact, if it is indeed true?

Comment: In the $ds$-integral you can do that. The set of $s$ with $X_{s-}\not=X_s$ is, as you say, countable hence has Lebesgue measure zero.

Comment: perfect that's what I was also thinking, but do you think the expression with $X_{s-}+\beta_s$ is correct? Can one justify this by saying that the size of jump $\beta_s (\Delta N)_s?$

Comment: I think it is because the jump $F(s,X_s) -F(s,X_{s-})$ is non zero if and only if $\Delta X_s=X_s-X_{s-}$ is non zero. In that case the latter is $\beta_s$ because the jump of $N_s$ is one. In short: the jump of $F(s,X_s)$ is either zero or $F(s,X_{s-}+\beta_s) -F(s,X_{s-})\,.$

Comment: I see that you still have doubts (bounty & cross post to MO). Is it your first formula that follows from the Ito formula (complicated for semimartingales)? Or what exactly are your doubts? I am of the opinion that our own reasoning is as good as a reputable source and there may not always one for every question. They give us an Ito formula and a Poisson process and let us do the rest ourselves. Let's go and do that.

Answer (score -1):

You got it, you can replace Xs− with Xs in the ds integral. The reason is:

The set of jump times {s : Ns ≠ Ns−} is at most countable (as it is a subset of the jump times of a Poisson process)
For any fixed s, Xs = Xs− outside of this countable set
Therefore, the difference F(s, Xs) − F(s, Xs−) is zero for almost every s, and the integral is unchanged if you replace Xs− with Xs

So your final expression is correct. This is a standard trick when working with Itô integrals - you can replace the "pre-jump" value of the process with the post-jump value in the diffusion term, as long as you are careful to keep the "correct" value in the jump term.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format equations.